# Replace multiple specific words in a static string literal with JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, replace, jsx

Attempting to replace specific words in a static string literal with JSX [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-wood-phnunq?file=/src/App.js:0-534) and getting an expected side effect. Only one specific word out of the multiple words takes effect.

```
import "./styles.css";

const Button = ({ children }) => <button>{children}</button>;

const text = "some text with the word email and call in it";

export default function App() {
  const nodes = text
    .split(new RegExp(`(\\b${"email" && "call"}\\b)`, "i"))
    .map((node, i) => (i % 2 ? <Button>{node}</Button> : node));

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <p>{nodes}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Also I tried to map over the words like so:

```
import "./styles.css";

const Button = ({ children }) => <button>{children}</button>;

const words = ["email", "call"];

const text = "some text with the word email and call in it";

export default function App() {
  const nodes = text
    .split(new RegExp(`(\\b${words.map((word) => word)}\\b)`, "i"))
    .map((node, i) => (i % 2 ? <Button>{node}</Button> : node));

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <p>{nodes}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[code pen](https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-wood-phnunq?file=/src/App.js:0-534)

Comment: `/(email|call)/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use [regular express alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) to match any of several words.

If you're just hard-coding the words to replace use the following simplified expression...

```js
text.split(/\b(email|call)\b/i);
```

Otherwise, if you have an array of words, something like this should work

```js
text.split(new RegExp(`\\b(${words.join("|")})\\b`, "i"));
```

The word-boundaries `\b` prevent you from accidentally matching words containing the searches like *"emailing"* or *"calling"*.

[image: Edit dazzling-solomon-hg7ixu]